# Coordinatorlayout doesnt work with included toolbar

Tags: android, layout

I have an appBarLayout with a toolbar and tabs and a pageview with a nested scroll and scroll flags so the toolbar disapears when i scroll inside the pageview, if the bar and pageview is in the same layout under coordinatorlayout it all works fine, but if i move the appBarLayout and include it in the main layout it doesnt anymore, i have no idea why. This is what i have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_include"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_include">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my appBarLayout in a separate layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1770B6"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#176FB6"
            app:tabTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

if i put them together it works perfectly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#1770B6"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#176FB6"
                    app:tabTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            >

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The layouts are not identical. In the 1st you are using 2 LL

Comment: i can remove the liniar layout it and it doesnt work, its there si the viewpager doesnt go on top of the toolbar

Comment: In the 1st remove also app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf in the viewPager

Comment: I did, the toolbar still doesn't scroll

Comment: The `AppBarLayout` must be a direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`. Get rid of both `LinearLayout`s, so the `AppBarLayout` is the root in the included layout. The `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` will keep the `ViewPager` below the `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: thank you, it worked, didnt know it has to be a direct child